# Allow html tags?

Tags: nodes

The full html setting is only allowing certain tags to go through. How do I turn this off and allow all tags?

> Full HTML
>   Allowed HTML tags: `<a> <blockquote> <br> <cite> <code> <dd> <div> <dl> <dt> <em> <li> <ol> <p> <span> <strong> <ul>`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to edit the filter.

Go to http://mysite.com/admin/config/content/formats/full_html, un-tick the "Limit allowed HTML tags" checkbox and press "Save configuration".

**EDIT**

Note that the above is for Drupal 7. For Drupal 6 go to http://mysite.com/admin/settings/filters and click "configure" on the Full HTML format. Then un-tick the "HTML filter" checkbox and again press "Save configuration".

Comment: its not allowing iframes, is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Take a peek at [this](http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/html-striped-body), it should help